# Unix Text File Manipulation

Tags: unix, text

I would like to change the first text file to the second:

1st: Input:

```
"127.0.0.1"
"Local"
"abph64ct"
"142.239.85.245"
"Omnipro"
"Abbs1"
```

2nd: Desired Output:

```
"127.0.0.1" "Local" "abph64ct"
"142.239.85.245" "Omnipro" "Abbs1"
```

Basically, I would like three fields on each line.
This example only shows two 'iterations'; there could be many more.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. **You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you.** Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: Which tools have you been taught?  It could be done non-trivially with `sed`, easily with `awk` or Perl or Python.  It could be done in pure shell with no external commands at all, come to that. Unless you show us what you tried, we can't tell how to help you.

Comment: cat InputFile.txt | tr -d "\n" | tr -d "\r"  I used this command - but it removed all carriage returns.   So I've been searching for a means of removing one CR at a time - once I find that I'll put it inside of Loop. Basically remove two CR's then skip the 3rd - repeat until EOF.  Ideas ?

Comment: My skill are pretty weak - When a have a task I search around for applicable commends then learn them well enough to complete the task.  . . .  mostly Unix commandline scripts and MS batch files.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`paste`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?paste) command as shown below, to place three fields on each line:

```
$ paste -d " " - - - < file
"127.0.0.1" "Local" "abph64ct"
"142.239.85.245" "Omnipro" "Abbs1"
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip about the 'paste' command - I'm trying that now

Comment: Thanks to all who replied. The 'paste' command recommended by dogbane worked perfectly - I'll add it to my notes.